# Best method to get sibling folders

Tags: winforms, algorithm, directory

Consider a scenario like this

Root

|-----a

|-----**b** (current folder)

|-----c

|-----etc...

- The current folder is **b**
- We need to find all folders on the same level as **b**.
- In other words, What's the best method to get '**a**' and '**c**' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow steps similar to @jstarek, but I would drop the second one.

Get the full path to folder b, strip out folder b from the path, list the directories in that path, and exclude folder b from the resulting set.

If you want information more specific to a programming language, please cite which one you are using. You mentioned WinForms so I would guess it's going to be .Net? If so, the .Net framework already has classes designed to complete this task.

EDIT:

If you're using .Net take a look at the DirectoryInfo class. It has a GetDirectories method that allows you to list the directories underneath a given directory very easily. It also has overloads for searching etc.

When I have used this in the past, exceptions can be thrown if the user running the program does not have permissions on the folder in question.

Here is a link to a sample of the DirectoryInfo GetDirectory method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx#Y798

Answer (score 3):

System independent:

- Store your current folder in some scratch variable.
- `cd` upwards, so that, in your example, you are in the root folder
- List all the folders there. This should give you **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**...
- Put that list in some suitable data structure.
- remove the folder you stored in the first step from said data structure (since you only require the siblings, not the starting folder itself).

Comment: ty for answering.But those are the basic steps. I want to know whether it is advisable to use recursion or windows API calls to achieve this purpose.